# Set and read cookies using two different domain using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, salesforce, apex-code

I want to set cookies in url like salesforce apex page url using javascript[document.cookie] and get those cookies in another domain in same browser.using javacript but not able to get.

Actually my Apex page which i load in iframe and that time i set that cookies and get those cookies in another page which is out side of salesforce domain.

Any body have any idea how to set and get cookies using different domains.

Comment: You cannot read cookies in another domain as it poses security risks

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to read cookies created by another domain for security reasons. I also believe the browser handles the creation of the domain aspect of the cookie, so I don't believe it's possible to create a cookie "from" another domain.

I don't think what you're asking is possible on separate domains (sub-domains would work)

Answer (score 1):

It is not going to work the way you want. You cannot read the cookie of another domain. You could think about using cross window messaging - especially if you are using iframes.

Comment: Can you please explain what r u saying about i-frame ?

Comment: There is the possibility, that a webpage and a embedded iframe communicate over a simple messaging system. You can find a description for example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.postMessage
This way you can use a iframe as some sort of proxy to communicate with a domain.

Comment: Another way to communicate between origins is CORS. Just google it. You can find a comparison between CORS and iframes with messaging here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186581/benefit-of-cors-over-cross-domain-messaging

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to read cookies created by another domain for security reasons. For get read same domain cookies use following code

```
    if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
    cookieArray = document.cookie.split(";");
    cookieArray.forEach(myFunction);

    function myFunction(item, index) {
        if (item.split("=")[0] == " yourcookiename" || item.split("=")[0] == "yourcookiename") {
            userSubID = item.split("=")[1];
            console.log("yourcookiename " + yourcookiename)
        }
    }
}
```

If there are more one cookie you have to use "(space)yourcookiename" and "yourcookiename" get cookie vales