# Drawbacks of storing information in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, web, local-storage, session-cookies

What are the drawbacks in storing the information in local storage or cookies under your website's domain vs storing the cookies under the third party vendors domain?

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of control.  Do you want access to the data yourself or do you want the third party to access it?  Which ever one you choose, the other is locked out.  Access is granted to cookies and local storage only to the same domain and protocol that set those cookies in the first place.  See: [Set and read cookies using two different domain using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163476/set-and-read-cookies-using-two-different-domain-using-javascript)