# Securing postMessage cross-origin

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, postmessage

I have two web pages on different domains, and I control both pages's code.

Domain-A opens Domain-B using `window.open` and then Domain-B does some client-side processing (can't be moved to server-side) and then uses `postMessage` to post the results back.

But before posting those results I want to make sure, that `window.opener` is actually me.

The problem is: **Domain-A varies** and can be anything (clients host my app on their own domains), while Domain-B is fixed. So I can't just set `targetOrigin` in my `postMessage`, because the origin is different all the time. I know I can simply use `'*'` and it will work fine, but that's not secure enough.

**So before sending a `postMessage` I want to verify that my page has really been `window.opened` by my code** while the domain that hosts the code - varies.

The only solution I came up with is async-cryptography. Add a public-key-encrypted signature query-string to `window.open` and then verify that signature by using `crypto.subtle.verify` on Domain-B using paired key.

Am I on the right track? Are there any easier options, or may be even best practices? Seems like I'm reinventing the wheel here...

Comment: Instead of doing this client-side, you could send a CORS-enabled AJAX request from A to B and retrieve the response without risk of tampering.

Comment: @mateleco I can't, I have to stay client-side, b/c Domain-B hosts some client-side 3rd party libraries (g-suite apps, like google drive picker and also some google maps stuff)

Answer (score 1):

Using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an option. There's an option to make credentialed requests passing auth information. Being an admin on both domains makes this easier. You could use Access-Control-Allow-Origin setting in your domains to allow them to make credentialed requests.

There's a well-written article MDN has that explains better than me: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Headers you could include in your requests:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers

And this section will be of interest, since you'd like to make sure posts are your code:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Requests_with_credentials

Comment: CORS is not remotely helpful when dealing with `postMessage`

Comment: @Quentin Yes, that's correct. CORS is a better alternative for the use case described. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186581/benefit-of-cors-over-cross-domain-messaging.

Note that Alex mentions: "Are there any easier options, or may be even best practice?" in his question.

Comment: @Thomas unfortunately I have to stay client-side, b/c domain B hosts some 3rd party client-side libs (Google Drive picker, Google maps stuff etc) that work on client side only. Of course there's an option to go server-side partially, and thanks for the info anyway, upvoted

Comment: @Thomas Actually, I just realized I should just do some server-side "handshake" between the two sites and then do the `window.open` part with some temporary tokens, that result from this handshake. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction